# difference between a combinatorial map and a rotation system?

Tags: combinatorics, topological-graph-theory

Wikipedia has separate articles for [combinatorial map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_map) and for [rotation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_system), but as far as I can tell, their formal definitions are identical.  Am I missing something?  Or do these terms have different meanings in practice?

Comment: I’ve just been wondering the same thing, and came across your question. Did you ever find out the answer?